# My DLL does not work as expected in RStudio

Tags: r, dll, rstudio

I have a DLL (made with Haskell). When I use it from the classical Rgui, it works as expected:

```
dyn.load("myDLL.dll)
.C("intAtBaseR", b=2L, n=10L, result=list(0L))$result[[1]]
# [1] 0 1 0 1
```

This is the binary expansion of the integer 10.

But when I use it from RStudio (1.1.463), with the same R, it gives unpredictable results:

```
.C("intAtBaseR", b=2L, n=10L, result=list(0L))$result[[1]]
# [1]       0       1 1259560       0
.C("intAtBaseR", b=2L, n=10L, result=list(0L))$result[[1]]
# [1]       0       1 1537624       0
```

What could be the reason of that ? Is there a known problem with DLLs in this version of RStudio ?